# SQL if else in proc isn't working properly - beginner friendly

Tags: postgresql

i'm pretty new to SQL and struggling with the last piece on my final project.  Logically, I know how to do it (i think) I just can't get the syntax correct.

I have a teaches table and an instructor table.  The teaches tables tells you what instructor has taught what class, when and for how many credits.  The instructor table is obviously a table with IDs and instructor names.  Finally, I have a table instructor_taught which really serves no purpose other than for us to learn.  this table holds instructor's IDs and how many total credits they have taught.

My challenge is to create a proc that takes an instructor's ID and adds or updates their total credits taught in the instructor_taught table.

First: check if the ID already exists in the instructor_taught table...if it does not exist then I need to add it to the table.  If it does exist then I need to update the entry and add the additional 3 credits. so if instructor 101 is already in the table with 3 total credits then I need to update the 3 to 6 instead of creating a new row.

I was able to create a proc that adds the instructor to the instructor_taught table but the update part is failing...so if i enter id:101 10x it will add that instructor 10x instead of updating.

Here is my code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  Day_21_monthlyPayment (IN id VARCHAR(30), INOUT d_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS
    $$
    
    BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT teaches.id, instructor.name, COUNT(*) AS d_count
        FROM teaches NATURAL JOIN instructor
        WHERE teaches.id = Day_21_monthlyPayment.id
        GROUP BY teaches.id, instructor.name;
    END
        IF EXISTS(SELECT teaches.id FROM teaches)
            THEN UPDATE instructor_course_nums SET tot_courses = d_count
            WHERE teaches.id = Day_21_monthlyPayment.id
        ELSE INSERT INTO instructor_course_nums (id, name, tot_courses)
    END IF;
    END;
    $$
```

I"m pretty sure this is a simple if else statement but i can't get the syntax right.  Thanks in advance!

DDL:

```
    CREATE TABLE instructor(
    ID VARCHAR(12),
    name VARCHAR(30),
    section VARCHAR(30),
    salary NUMERIC(20)
    )

    CREATE TABLE teaches(
    ID VARCHAR(12),
    course VARCHAR(30),
    count VARCHAR(30),
    term VARCHAR(20),
    year NUMERIC(20)
    )

    CREATE TABLE instructor_course_nums(
    ID VARCHAR(12),
    name VARCHAR(30),
    tot_courses NUMERIC(2)
    )
```

Comment: Can you include your table structures?  I think the procedure might be overkill and all you need is one DML statement.  Alternatively, you can replace the table that has credits with a view, and then you never need to do updates...  but start by showing your DDL.

Comment: hey @Hambone - thanks for the quick reply.  I edited the above to show the 3 tables I'm working with.  There probably is a better way to do this; however, the project requirements are to use a proc.

in another comment i will post the question that i'm working on

Comment: For this problem create a table called instructor_course_nums within the university
database schema. Write a procedure that accepts an instructor ID as input. The procedure
calculates the total number of course sections taught by that instructor, and adds a tuple to
the instructor_course_nums table consisting of the instructors ID number, name, and total
courses taught - call these attributes: ID, name, and tot_courses. If the instructor already
has an entry in the table, then the procedure makes sure the total number of courses
taught in the instructor_course_nums table is up-to-date.

Comment: 1) Put your explanation as update to question not as comment. 2) Get rid of the inner `BEGIN` and `END` lines, they are not doing what  you  think(I'm assuming you think they a transaction) 3) Pretty sure `IF EXISTS(SELECT teaches.id FROM teaches)` is not doing what you think it is, namely using the `teacher_id` from your previous select.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are forced to do a procedure, I think you can still do this in (nearly) one fell swoop with a single DML statement.  Assuming you have the proper constraints (primary key), I would think something like this would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  Day_21_monthlyPayment (idx VARCHAR(30), INOUT d_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  into d_count
  FROM teaches t JOIN instructor i on t.id = i.id
  WHERE t.id = idx;

  insert into instructor_course_nums
  select t.id, t.name, d_count
  from instructor t
  where t.id = idx
  on conflict (id) do
  update
    set tot_courses = d_count;
  
END;
$BODY$
```

Comment: No problemo.  I just realized the population of d_count was overengineered...  there is no need for the join.  It can be simplified to:  `SELECT COUNT(*) into d_count FROM teaches WHERE id = '1';`